How to use securityConfigSecret in Opensearch with admin password being a sensitive value
I'm trying to use a set of roles with custom-defined permissions and OIDC as authentication backend for the OpenSearch cluster deployed using opensearch-operator. I also want to have the password for the admin user defined separately. I can use the securityConfigSecret to provide all these configs using a secret as follows.
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: opensearch-security-config
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
type: Opaque
stringData:
  internal_users.yml: |-
    _meta:
      type: "internalusers"
      config_version: 2
    admin:
      hash: <MY-CUSTOM-PW-HASH>
      reserved: true
      backend_roles:
      - "admin"
      description: "Internal admin user"
  config.yml: |-
    _meta:
      type: "config"
      config_version: 2
    config:
      dynamic:
        http:
          anonymous_auth_enabled: false
        authc:
          basic_internal_auth_domain:
            description: "Authenticate via HTTP Basic against internal users database"
            http_enabled: true
            transport_enabled: true
            order: "1"
            http_authenticator:
              type: basic
              challenge: true
            authentication_backend:
              type: intern
          oidc_auth_domain:
            description: "Authenticate via OpenID Connect"
            http_enabled: true
            transport_enabled: true
            order: 0
            http_authenticator:
              type: openid
              challenge: false
              config:
                subject_key: username
                roles_key: roles
                openid_connect_url: <My-OIDC-AUTH-PROVIDER>
            authentication_backend:
              type: noop
        authz: {}
  roles_mapping.yml: |-
    _meta:
      type: "rolesmapping"
      config_version: 2
    all_access:
      reserved: false
      backend_roles:
      - "admin"
      - "opensearch_admin"
      description: "Maps admin role and opensearch_admin to all_access"
    alerts_management:
      reserved: false
      backend_roles:
      - "opensearch_alerts_mgmt"
      description: "Maps opensearch_alerts_mgmt role to alerts_management"
    read_only:
      reserved: false
      backend_roles:
      - "opensearch_readonly"
      - "opensearch_alerts_mgmt"
      description: "Maps opensearch_readonly role to read_only"
  roles.yml: |-
    _meta:
      type: "roles"
      config_version: 2
    alerts_management:
      reserved: false
      cluster_permissions:
        - "cluster:admin/opensearch/securityanalytics/*"
        - "cluster:admin/opendistro/alerting/*"
    read_only:
      reserved: false
      cluster_permissions:
        - "cluster_composite_ops_ro"
        - "cluster_monitor"
        - "cluster:admin/opensearch/observability/get"
        - "cluster:admin/opensearch/ppl"
        - "cluster:admin/opensearch/ql/datasources/read"
      index_permissions:
        - index_patterns:
            - "*"
          allowed_actions:
            - "read"
            - "search"
            - "get"
            - "indices_monitor"
            - "indices:admin/mappings/get"
      tenant_permissions:
        - tenant_patterns:
            - "*"
          allowed_actions:
            - "kibana_all_read"


However, the password hash for the admin user is a sensitive value in the above config secret, and other configs can be seen as not sensitive contents. Therefore it would be better if we can have the above config secret file on GitHub for future modifications for roles and permissions. But at the moment it cannot be done only because of the admin password hash. Is there any way I can extract the password out and provide it into the deployment in a different way?

It's common enough to pass this sort of data as Helm values (though that requires the entity running helm install to have the value, and helm get values can retrieve it).  Have you tried that approach already?

Thanks for the input. But in this case, deployment takes place through a CI/CD pipeline and therefore I cannot enter the sensitive data in a values file. I need to use a key vault like azure to refer to the password hash at the deployment time
